# sinonjs - stub a library referenced internally as a function using node modules (no require)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon, es6-modules, stub

I have an external library that is exported as a function, in the [Stub documentation](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v11.1.2/stubs/#var-stub--sinonstubobject-method) it only accepts an input with the first parameter as object and the second parameter as method , so how could I stub a library that is exported as a function in a Node ES Modules environment (without Commonjs)?

(In my specific case, I had used a library that use the internet to work, and I wanted to test derivated functions without accessing the internet, so I want to stub the external function library)

Attempts:

- I couldn't use solutions like [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) as it is a solution based on `require` and `module cache deletion`, which are not supported within Node's ES modules.
- I don't want to use [proxyquire-universal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire-universal) because it simulates the operation of `require` in normal ES, and it's just a function in the whole project that I wanted to test, I was looking for a simpler solution
- Changing the import mode doesn't work as it's not recompiled like in `babel`, so even if I import as `import * as obj from 'lib'` only the function name is changed

I had this error environment with 3 files:

> An external library called "sum" for example, which I don't want to change, exported as follows:
>
> > **External Library: externalSum.js**
> >
> > ```
> > module.exports = function sum(a, b){
> >   console.log(">>>>> running without stub <<<<<")
> >   return a + b
> > }
> > ```
>
> This library used in the middle of a project file called mathProblems
>
> > **Internal File: mathProblems.js**
> >
> > ```
> > import sum from 'externalSum'
> >
> > export function sumMore1(a) {
> >   return sum(a, 1);
> > }
> > ```
>
> And I have a test file
>
> > **Internal File: spec.js**
> >
> > ```
> > import sinon from 'sinon'
> > import assert from 'assert'
> > import sumObj from 'externalSum'
> > import { sumMore1 } from '../mathProblems.js'
> >
> > describe('sumMore1 is working', () => {
> >   it('sumMore1 test', () => {
> >     const sum_stub = sinon.stub(sumObj) // NOT STUBBING
> >     sum_stub.withArgs(1, 1).returns(2) // NOT STUBBING
> >
> >     const result = sumMore1(1)
> >     assert.strictEqual(result, 2)
> >   });
> > });
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find this solution anywhere on the internet, i found some solutions that work for node with request or babilon, but not for my case using ES Modules:

- https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562
- https://minaluke.medium.com/how-to-stub-spy-a-default-exported-function-a2dc1b580a6b

So I wanted to register the solution in case anyone needs it.

---

To solve this, create a new file, which can be allocated anywhere in the project, in this case I will call it sumImport.js:

> **Internal File: sumImport.js**
>
> ```
> import sum from 'externalSum';
>
> // export as object
> export default {
>   sum
> }
> ```

The object needs to be called inside the created function I want to test, and changed the import way:

> **Internal File: mathProblems.js**
>
> ```
> import sumObj from './sumImport.js';
>
> export function sumMore1(a) {
>   const { sum } = sumObj;
>   return sum(a, 1);
> }
> ```

And I finally managed to import as an object in the test:

> **Internal File: spec.js**
>
> ```
> import sinon from 'sinon'
> import assert from 'assert'
> import sumObj from '../sumImport.js'
> import { sumMore1 } from '../mathProblems.js'
>
> describe('sumMore1 is working', () => {
>   it('sumMore1 test', () => {
>     const sum_stub = sinon.stub(sumObj, "sum") // STUBBED
>     sum_stub.withArgs(1, 1).returns(2) // STUBBED
>
>     const result = sumMore1(1)
>     assert.strictEqual(result, 2)
>   });
> });
> ```

---

I hope it helps someone and if someone else has some better solutions I would also be grateful!